# Adding Away3D video texture to object in Flex Mobile

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, stage3d, away3d

I'm using Away3D v4 in a Flex Mobile project. Is it possible to add a video texture to a plane?

It seem to work fine running on the AIR simulator in Flash Builder, but doesn't render at all on Android.

Here's the code I'm using to create the texture:

```
var videoTexture:VideoTexture = new VideoTexture("MyVideo.flv");
var material = new TextureMaterial(videoTexture);
var mesh = new Mesh(new PlaneGeometry(500, 500), material);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the H.264 video was being rendered by the Android GPU and appearing directly on the StageVideo layer below Stage3D, even though I was using the Video component not StageVideo. Videos encoded with VP6 work fine as a 3D texture, but are slow due to CPU decoding.